# In a GORM findBy* query, how can I use "sort" before limiting using "max"

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The following grails query will limit the number of results to 3 and then sort those by id:

`def results = Domain.findAllByFoo(foo, [sort: 'id', order: 'desc', max: 3])`

So this will return ids 1 through 3, and then reverse their order, so that

`results*.id == [3,2,1]`

Is there a way to sort first, and limit after, so that

`results*.id == [99,98,97]`

My current workaround is this:

`if (results.size() > max) results = results[0..<max]`

Comment: Are you sure that `findAllBy` sorts after limit? What database do you use?

Comment: hmmm, I encountered it in a unit test. might be a bug in the new unit testing database mocking?

Comment: Can you please put the sql generated by that HQL? We are using similar hql in our project and it works fine.  BTW -We wrote integration test case to test this functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a [bug in Grails](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8993) that is fixed in 2.0.4.